# Decompress wav file (Windows IMA ADPCM compression) in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have some `wav` files that were presumably created on a Windows system and need to be decompressed (ideally "on the fly") in an Objective-C app.  The compression code is 17 -- IMA ADPCM.  I've found [some source](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/algorithm-alley/184410326), but would prefer to use something built-in if it's accessible, especially since there are apparently several different variants of the algorithm.

Do does anyone know of an API or such that can be used to do the decompression?

**Update:** Trying to use Extended Audio File Services, but I can't get past setting the "ClientDataFormat".  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11268962/581994).

Answer (score 1):

The built-in [`AVFoundation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html) framework will play .wav files.

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to play the file.

Comment: Oh, I see. It looks like [Extended Audio File Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) might do what you want. I haven't used it, though, so can't say for sure.

Comment: Well, I've been trying to use Extended Audio File Services, but, try as I might, I cannot get the system to accept a client format property specification, and you apparently can't do anything until you do that.